# How to pass the SELECT statement as a parameter to stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

What is wrong with my code? I want to pass the select statement and where clause variable values:

```
ALTER PROC sp_ac_getItemLookupCode 
    @itemlookupcode varchar(20) = null,
    @select varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCTT
        @select
    FROM
        [ReportHQMatajer].[dbo].[JFC_ItemDailySalesParent] pp
    WHERE 
        ItemLookupCode LIKE @itemlookupcode+'%' 
END
```

Above is my stored procedure. I execute the following code, but it returns the column `Name` only

```
sp_ac_getItemLookupCode @select='ItemLookupCode',@itemlookupcode=1
```

It is not returning all the values. It returns the **column name** as a result

Comment: Research "dynamic SQL"

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dynamic query via using `SP_EXECUTESQL` system stored proecures as next:-

```
ALTER PROC sp_ac_getItemLookupCode 
@itemlookupcode varchar(20)= null,
@select varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
declare @Query nvarchar(2000)
set @Query = 
    'select distinct ' + @select + '
    FROM
        [ReportHQMatajer].[dbo].[JFC_ItemDailySalesParent] pp
    WHERE 
        ItemLookupCode like ''' + @itemlookupcode+ + '%'' '
exec sp_executesql @Query
END
```

Comment: will it cause Sql injection?

Comment: @Abbas The code is tested !, plz copy the above code and re-execute it, waiting ur feedback

Comment: just add a single quataion after `like` . BTW, Click `edited n mins ago` link under the answer for knowing what are the changes exactly .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass column names as a parameter then you have to make your dynamic query, as next:-

```
Exec ('select distinct '+@select+'
    FROM
        [ReportHQMatajer].[dbo].[JFC_ItemDailySalesParent] pp')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass column names (or table names or function names or the like), you need to use dynamic SQL:

```
ALTER PROC sp_ac_getItemLookupCode (
    @itemlookupcode varchar(20) = null,
    @select varchar(30)
) AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql = nvarchar(max);

    set @sql = '
select distinct @select
from [ReportHQMatajer].[dbo].[JFC_ItemDailySalesParent] pp
';

    set @sql = replace(@sql, '@select', @select);

    if (@itemlookupcode is not null)
    begin
        set @sql = @sql + 'where ItemLookupCode like ''' + @itemlookupcode + '%'''
    end;

    exec sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

I added the functionality that if `@itemlookupcode` is `NULL`, then it returns all rows.